# How to mouseover vector features in openlayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

I want to be able to mouseover features in openlayers like this example (but i want to show the feature's name in a tooltip)

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/vector-layer.html?q=hover

The problem is I am getting  ol.FeatureOverlay is undefined.

I am using version:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.10.1/ol.js
```